# Calling Postgres Stored Procedure with arguments and insert values from a given select

Tags: database, postgresql

Say I have a select statement.

```
SELECT sensorname, starttime from sensors where id = ?;
```

It returns for instance:

```
Value1 | 123456789
Value1 | 987465465
```

(starttime is a timestamp)

Now I'd like to create a StoredProcedure within my Postgres.

```
someProcedure(argumentId){
   Result r = SELECT sensorname, starttime from sensors where id = ?;

}
```

Then it should loop over the resultSet, take the results and insert them into another table and finally remove the old ones from the origin table.

Is this possible with a storedProcedure?

Edit: I need a stored Procedure for this.

something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTIONrollupMinutes(id bigint) RETURNS void AS $$

BEGIN
    var qry_rsult = SELECT sensorname, starttime from sensors where id = id;
    insert into rollup(qry_result)   
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using CTE like below(*Only if you want to avoid a function*)

```
WITH cte (id)
AS (
    INSERT INTO another_table (sensorname,starttime)
    SELECT sensorname
          ,starttime
    FROM sensors WHERE id = id 
    returning id;
    )
DELETE
FROM
sensors
WHERE id IN (SELECT *FROM cte);
```

*OR*

By creating a function it can be like

```
create or replace function fn(id int) returns void as
$$
insert into another_table(sensorname,starttime)  
SELECT sensorname, starttime from sensors where id =id;
delete from sensors where id =id;
$$
language sql
```

Usage:

```
select fn(12)
```

Comment: I don't get how this cte plays together with the function

Comment: CTE is not working here with a function it's a different approach, I've added CTE method just for your information

Comment: ok. well thank you. What I actually wanted is selecting a subset from a table and inserting it into another table. then delete the original data. I can't see this within your answer.. Especially within the function (which is mostly intersting for me)

Comment: @Christian `insert into another_table(sensorname,starttime)  
SELECT sensorname, starttime from sensors where id =id;` will select ` sensorname, starttime` from  `sensors` table and insert them to another_table's `sensorname,starttime`(Or your desired column1,column2).After that `delete from sensors where id =id;` will delete values from table `sensors`